# ADT failed to run on windows 7 32bit

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, compatibility

I have a problem with running "**adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030**" software on my laptop. I have a 32bit version of windows 7 and of course 32bit version of jre. When I want to run eclipse under that program, it fails with message:

"**The version of this file is not compatible with the version of windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher**."

Why this is happening? (In the download page of that software it said that can be used in both 32bit and 64bit environment!).

Comment: @rekire: I tried that but still that message. Even the name of program said that it is for both x86 and x64!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That package name contains x86_64 which points out that this is a x64 build and not a x86 as the name could been interpreted as.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64):

> x86-64 (also known as x64, x86_64 andAMD64) is the 64-bit version of the x86instruction set.

You can download the latest version of the adt plugin from the Android homepage:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: Really!! I thought that when it said x86_64, it means it is for both 23bit and 64bit versions! Can you please give me a link for 32bit version of adt-bundle-windows :(

Comment: Sorry no idea I develop android apps with android studio which uses gradle as build system which is much greater than eclipse

Comment: Thanks a lot, which version of android studio are you using? is it as powerful as eclipse?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply it is IMHO much more powerful than eclipse. I'm using the version 0.8.11. The dependency handling is very cool you don't need to download any plugins/addons anymore if they are on the maven central. Try [this zip file](https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip). I switched in January from Eclipse to Android Studio and I don't want to switch back.

Comment: By the way you can download Android Studio from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html. **Note**:  0.8.11 is currently only available in the canary channel, and Android Studio Beta will by default only look for updates in the beta channel, so if you want to update, open the preference dialog, go to the Updates category and change the channel setting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link for 32bit version of adt-bundle-windows 7. [http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html]

Comment: @HaMi go to this link and press blue button After that check on 32 bit radio button and press Download button..and your problem solve:)